# LibGDX - saving screenshot in write protected folder

Tags: java, libgdx

My class for saving screenshots works fine:

```
public class ScreenshotSaver {

    private static int counter = 1;

    public static void saveScreenshot() {
        FileHandle fh;
        do {
            fh = new FileHandle("screenshot" + counter++ + ".png");
        } while (fh.exists()); 
        Pixmap pixmap = getScreenshot(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);        
        PixmapIO.writePNG(fh, pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();
    }

    private static Pixmap getScreenshot(int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean flipY) {
        Gdx.gl.glPixelStorei(GL10.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

        final Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(w, h, Format.RGBA8888);
        ByteBuffer pixels = pixmap.getPixels();
        Gdx.gl.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

        final int numBytes = w * h * 4;
        byte[] lines = new byte[numBytes];
        if (flipY) {
            pixels.clear();
            pixels.get(lines);

        } else {
            final int numBytesPerLine = w * 4;
            for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
                    pixels.position((h - i - 1) * numBytesPerLine);
                    pixels.get(lines, i * numBytesPerLine, numBytesPerLine);
            }
            pixels.clear();
            pixels.put(lines);
        }

        return pixmap;
    }

}
```

The problem is, when I execute program in write protected area. Program simply turns off. I'd prefer if it just didn't save the screenshot instead. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use a try/catch?

```
try{
  PixmapIO.writePNG(fh, pixmap);
} catch (Exception e) {
  // save it somewhere else
}
pixmap.dispose();
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel a bit stupid now for not trying that out... :/ I thought every method that throws exception has to have `throws` clause.

Comment: Sounds like you never learned what exceptions are really for:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Definitely worth learning!

Answer (score 0):

For runtime file writing you use `Gdx.files.local(...)`. See [file handling](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling#file-storage-types) in the libgdx wiki. It works everywhere but with GWT/in the browser.